# Binary Search Tree implementation

Tags: c, memory-management, tree, binary-search

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct Node NODE;

struct Node {
  int value;
  int is_leaf;
  struct Node *right;
  struct Node *left;
};

NODE *new_leaf(void) {
  NODE *leaf = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
  assert(leaf);
  leaf->is_leaf = 1;
  leaf->value = 0;
  leaf->right = NULL;
  leaf->left = NULL;
  return leaf;
}

int insert(NODE *node, int value) {
  assert(node);
  if (node->is_leaf) {
    node->is_leaf = 0;
    node->value = value;
    node->left = new_leaf();
    node->right = new_leaf();
  } else if (node->value < value) {
    return insert(node->left, value);
  } else if (node->value > value) {
    return insert(node->right, value);
  }
  return -1;
}

int contains(NODE *node, int value) {
  assert(node);
  if (node->is_leaf) {
    return 0;
  } else if (node->value < value) {
    return contains(node->left, value);
  } else if (node->value > value) {
    return contains(node->right, value);
  } 
  return 1;
}

int max_height(NODE *node) {
  assert(node);
  if (node->is_leaf) {
    return 0;
  } 
  int left_height = max_height(node->left);
  int right_height = max_height(node->right);
  if (left_height > right_height) {
    return 1 + left_height;
  } else {
    return 1 + right_height;
  }
}

void destroy(NODE *tree) {
  free(tree);
}


int main(void) {
  NODE *tree = new_leaf();
  insert(tree, 7);
  printf("contains 7? : %d\n", contains(tree, 7));
  insert(tree, 6);
  printf("contains 6? : %d\n", contains(tree, 6));
  insert(tree, 5);
  printf("contains 5? : %d\n", contains(tree, 5));
  printf("height should be 3, is : %d\n", max_height(tree));
  insert(tree, 8);
  printf("contains 8? : %d\n", contains(tree, 8));
  printf("height should be 3, is : %d\n", max_height(tree));
  printf("no contains 1? : %d\n", contains(tree, 9));
  destroy(tree);
}
```

Looking for general style advice, and if I missed any memory leaks.

Specific question: does `destroy`ing the tree at the end free up all of the memory allocated for every node in the tree? If so, how? If not, how can I ensure that occurs? Also, am I using asserts correctly? It's very different than the languages I have used previously.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, in C, `ALL_CAPS` is generally used only for macros. Hence, I wouldn't use the name `NODE` as a `typedef` for your `struct node`, but instead something like `typedef struct Node node_type;`. Further, generally C is written using `lowercase_with_underscores`, so I'd rename it to `struct node`.

Using an `assert` in your `new_leaf` function on what you get back from `malloc` is fine in my books, as this will terminate the process if the OS can't give you back any memory, in which case you're unlikely to be able to do anything anyway.

Your function `int contains(NODE *node, int value)` doesn't really need an `assert`. If the user gives you a `NULL` node, then you can immediately just `return 0`. Giving a `NULL` to this function shouldn't terminate the program. A similar argument can be made for `max_height`.

Of course, the biggest problem is that no, your `destroy` function definitely does NOT clean up all the memory allocated by the program. Tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) can help to inform you if you have any memory leaks lurking around. In this case, however, it's very easy to see that the only memory that will be reclaimed is the memory for the root node (whatever you call `destroy` with).

Fixing this is pretty simple: it's just using a recursive algorithm that you've basically already used in `insert` and `contains`:

```
void destroy(node_type root)
{
    // If we have a non-NULL pointer, we need to
    // recursively free its left and right children,
    // and then free it.
    if(root) {
        destroy(root->left);
        destroy(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}
```

A few other comments:

- I'm not a big fan of 2 space indentation. It's not enough to (easily) visually scope blocks. I'd much rather 4 spaces.
- You might want to start looking into how to user header files to split up interface and implementation as a next step (if you haven't already).
- I'm not a big fan of explicitly having keeping track of what is a leaf with `is_leaf`. It means that any node that is down the bottom will have 2 extra dynamic allocations performed to have leaf values (see `insert`). Instead, I'd just set the `left` and `right` pointers to be `NULL`, and leave it at that. You can easily write an `is_leaf` function that simply checks that both pointers are `NULL`.
- The API is a bit deficient (no deletion of a value, for example), but I'm guessing this is done as a learning exercise, so that's ok.

Answer (score 2):

Specific questions first:

1. No, your `destroy` function does not destroy the entire tree - it just frees the current node and you'll leak all other nodes. You will have to implement a recursive delete similar to all your other functions:

   ```
   void destroy(NODE *node)
   {
       if (!node->is_leaf)
       {
           destroy(node->left);
           destroy(node->right);
       }
       free(node);
   }
   ```
2. I think your usage of `assert` is quite sensible. Just be aware that asserts are typically removed when build with `NDEBUG` defined - in that case your code will just segfault.

Some general remarks:

1. `UPPERCASE` names are typically only used for macros and not for typedefs.
2. I don't quite see the point of returning a value from insert. You always return -1 anyway.
3. Personally I'm not a fan of implementations where an element of the data structure is used to also represent the entry into the data structure. You are effectively leaking the internals if your implementation to the user. An alternative API would something like this:

   In your header:

   ```
   typedef struct BinarySearchTree BinarySearchTree;

   BinarySearchTree* bst_new_tree();
   void bst_insert(BinarySearchTree* tree, int value);
   int bst_contains_value(BinarySearchTree* tree, int value);
   int bst_max_height(BinarySearchTree* tree);
   ```

   In your implementation

   ```
   struct BinarySearchTree
   {
       Node *root;
   }

   ....
   ```

   This way any user of you data structure doesn't know anything about the internals which in turn makes it easy to change the implementation without affecting anything else.

   Typedefing the struct in the header but only defining it in the implementation file is called an opaque type - a type where the consumer of the header does not know anything about the internals of it.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't use memory very efficiently:

- The first node is initially a 'leaf' node which contains no useful value
- Every leaf node contains no useful value
- Every non-leaf node (which contains a value) contains two empty leaf nodes

It's a bit hard to see what's happening: initially-empty leaf nodes later have a value inserted into them.

A cleaner implementation might be:

- Every Node contains a value; the value is inserted in the Node when the Node is created and never changed afterwards
- A tree which contains no values is represented by a null Node pointer (i.e. zero Node instances)
- Left and right nodes aren't added until they're needed

To implement this:

- Add a `int value` parameter to the new_leaf function
- Remove the is_leaf member of the node
- Create left and right nodes just-in-time i.e. not before/until they are needed

For example:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *left;
};

NODE *new_leaf(int value) {
    NODE *leaf = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    assert(leaf);
    leaf->value = value;
    leaf->right = NULL;
    leaf->left = NULL;
    return leaf;
}

int insert(NODE *node, int value) {
    assert(node);
    if (node->value < value) {
        if (node->left)
            return insert(node->left, value);
        else
            node->left = new_leaf(value);
    } else { // if (node->value >= value)
        if (node->right)
            return insert(node->right, value);
        else
            node->right = new_leaf(value);
    }
    return -1;
}

int contains(NODE *node, int value) {
    assert(node);
    if (node->value == value) {
        return 1;
    } else if (node->value < value) {
        if (node->left)
            return contains(node->left, value);
    } else { // if (node->value > value)
        if (node->right)
            return contains(node->right, value);
    } 
    return 0;
}

int max_height(NODE *node) {
    assert(node);
    int left_height = (node->left) ? max_height(node->left) : 0;
    int right_height = (node->right) ? max_height(node->right) : 0;
    if (left_height > right_height) {
        return 1 + left_height;
    } else {
        return 1 + right_height;
    }
}

void destroy(NODE *tree) {
    NODE *left = tree->left;
    NODE *right = tree->right;
    free(tree);
    if (left)
        destroy(left);
    if (right)
        destroy(right);
}
```